# How to correctly create new class instance and handle to him?

Tags: node.js, oop

I created bots panel and to setup a new bot I create new class instance:

```
global.bots[account.name] = new Bot(account);
```

How much correct record new bot in global variable, for to access its methods? Example:

```
global.bots[account.name].stopBot
```

Sorry, if my question seems dumb, but I am a newbie. Hope for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

to access a method usually `()` are required and when arguments are needed try `(<argument1>, <argument2>)`

in your example

```
global.bots[account.name].stopBot()
```